# Find and replace from Terminal and write to a new file with the replaced values

Tags: macos, terminal.app, find-and-replace

I have a file `template.jou` that has the following format:

```
/codeline1
/codeline2
/var = var
/codeline3
```

Now I want to replace the `var` part with different values like `A`, `B` and `C` and then write the contents of `template.jou` with the replaced value to a new file.

I tried the following:

```
sed -n 's/var/A/gpw A.jou' template.jou
```

But this only printed the pattern matched line (i.e. `/var = A`) to the new file `A.jou` where I want the full file like this:

```
/codeline1
/codeline2
/var = A
/codeline3
```

I've also tried:

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/var/A/g' template.jou
```

This replaced the template.jou file with new contents, but I want it to change filename as well such that the new file is called `A.jou`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to redirect the output of `sed` to another file:

```
sed 's/= var/= A/g' template.jou > A.jou
```

Make sure that you replace just the assignment, e.g. by matching `= var` only.

---

Note that `'s/var/A/gp` will **not** achieve what you want, since `var` will globally be replaced, and the replacement will be printed again. You'd get this output instead:

```
/codeline1
/codeline2
/A = A
/A = A
/codeline3
```

Also, the `w` modifier only prints the modified part to the file specified after it, which means your `A.jou` would only contain `/var = A` and nothing else. This is why you should redirect the entire `sed` output to another file.